# Lenovo charging issue - help needed regarding the recently purchased charger

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power, lenovo-laptop, charging

I've got a Lenovo Ideapad 100S-11BY, Modal: 80R2 Laptop

I just recently bought this charger for it - [Charging Device Listing](https://www.takealot.com/5v-4a-charger-for-lenovo-ideapad-notebook-3-5mm-1-35mm-tip/PLID54588872)

When I plug in the charger into the laptops charging port, after about 10 to 20 seconds, the device gets quite warm on the underside near the charging port.

When I press the power button the device does not turn on, it was working previously on the last charge it had, and the device ran out of battery about 1 month ago.

any ideas or steps to fix it?

I would like to know before I submit a refund request for the charger to the reseller.

The MTM is: 80R2004RSA

## Edit 1

it gets hot in this place (not my actual device, but same underside as my device)

green: hot
blue: charging port
[image]

Comment: Laptops may not work well when the battery is completely dead. Is the dead battery situated in the area that warms up when the charger is connected?

Comment: @harrymc see my edit, its gets hot there

Comment: @harrymc fixed the image, i had it on the wrong side, sorry

Comment: Turn the laptop fully OFF.   Make sure OFF.  Then attach the charger and let run for 3 hours.  Does it now start and run without overheating?  If not, the battery may be faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to `80R2004RSA` seems to refer to the Ideapad 100S-11IBY.

From the
[Ideapad 100S-11IBY Hardware Maintenance Manual](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/100-series/100s-11iby/documentation/doc_userguide)
page 35:

[image]

So it seems that the spot that is getting warm is where is found
the battery pack connector.

This is not good and may even be dangerous.
I really recommend not to try and run this laptop without a functioning
battery.